Convergence barrier for branchless CUDA conditional select
I implemented a simple path tracing renderer and I've been profiling my code via ncu-ui. I found something confusing in the SASS generated by the CUDA compiler. Here is snippet that generates the confusing SASS instructions:
// CPT_GPU means '__device__' here
CPT_GPU float ray_intersect(
    const Ray& ray,
    ConstShapePtr shapes,
    ConstAABBPtr s_aabbs,
    ShapeIntersectVisitor& shape_visitor,
    int& min_index,
    const int remain_prims,
    const int cp_base_5,
    float min_dist
) {
    float aabb_tmin = 0;
    #pragma unroll
    for (int idx = 0; idx < remain_prims; idx ++) {
        if (s_aabbs[idx].intersect(ray, aabb_tmin) && aabb_tmin <= min_dist) {
            shape_visitor.set_index(idx);
            float dist = variant::apply_visitor(shape_visitor, shapes[cp_base_5 + idx]);
            bool valid = dist > EPSILON && dist < min_dist;
            min_dist = valid ? dist : min_dist;
            // ------------ the question stems from the line below ---------------
            min_index = valid ? cp_base_5 + idx : min_index;
        }
    }
    return min_dist;
}


The logic, for the sake of clarity, is fairly straightforward: the program traverses through all the triangles, and find the closest hit. If the hit is closer than the currently recorded minimal hit distance (then valid would be true), we record the triangle index in min_index. Otherwise, min_index remains unchanged. Yet in the SASS instructions, the min_index = valid ? cp_base_5 + idx : min_index; generates the following code:
SEL R24, R25, R24, P0      % Select Source with Predicate
BSYNC B8                   % Synchronize Threads on a Convergence Barrier

The profiler tells me that the min_index selection causes considerable amount of warp stalling (with 77.51% being "No instructions" and ~14% being "Branch resolving"). Also, the for loop in the code also introduces much warp stalling (with 50% being "Barrier"). So I wonder:

Why would compiler add BSYNC here? Isn't the code branchless and there is no explicit synchronization point? What's the point of this op?
Why does the for loop spend so much time stalling, for some barrier? What is this barrier? Why is it added? Is it because of SIMT that all threads in a warp should execute the same instruction so some threads have to wait?

The full code can be found here, if one cares to look into this. Easy compilation with CMake on an NV GPU device.

This is definitely related to branch divergence. This paper may be of interest for you: Sana Damani e.t.al: Speculative Reconvergence for Improved SIMT Efficiency. In particular, the section starting with Divergent Conditions in Loops seems to be exactly your use case

The "if" introduces a branch and then the for needs a jump which requires a sync before the next iteration of the for loop.

@Homer512 that is exactly the case, thanks a lot. I've read the paper and I think loop merge is an interesting point. Though I have no clue how it is implemented... :( and sadly this is one of the speed bottleneck of my code. So why there is no official compiler optimization from nvcc for this case?

I wonder if restructuring the code like this helps: https://godbolt.org/z/o37cnPrEr

@Homer512 I will try this later. Actually the paper recommended has already been very helpful. I refactored the code (if you are interested, check this link, I renamed the older version of ray_intersection to ray_intersection_old and the new ray_intersection is the version aftering refactoring) and doubled the rendering speed , while other memory access improvements only result in around 15% speed up. This is amazing. I will do a profiling later and conclude this post with an answer. Thanks again!

Ah yes. I also thought about that. You can combine both approaches if you want remain_prims to be larger than 32. Just make an outer loop and inside that loop search and process up to 32 tasks.

@Homer512 I copy the triangles from gmem to smem (multiple times) and each time, up to 32 triangles are processed. So, things work just fine. Profiling definitely needs more work though, since I observed some performance inconsistency across different platforms.

Not all platforms cache local arrays in L1 cache. That might be a reason. If it's always 32 at most, you can replace the tasks array with a 32 bit mask and use __ffs or __fns to find the next task in the second loop

I've done the profiling, and what surprises me is that on 3060 laptop, the performance gets even worse than the original implementation, yet on a 2060 workstation, the performance is boosted by almost 2.5x. I really don't understand why this is so, and one of my friend tells me that maybe for 3060 (related arch), the compiler is less performant (not verified) since the same program only needs 64 registers on 2060 machine while 72 registers are needed for 3060. This is indeed weird, so I will only break down what boosts the speed on the 2060 workstation.
As pointed out by @Homer512 and @Johan, BSYNC here is related to branch divergence. The paper recommended by @Homer512 illustrates this, and I put a figure from that paper below:

I think the paper is inspiring and based on the idea of loop merging, the code is first refactored into the following:
    float aabb_tmin = 0;
    int8_t tasks[32] = {0}, cnt = 0;          // 32 bytes
#pragma unroll
    for (int idx = 0; idx < remain_prims; idx++) {
        // if current ray intersects primitive at [idx], tasks will store it
        int valid_intr = s_aabbs[idx].intersect(ray, aabb_tmin);       // valid intersect
        tasks[cnt] = valid_intr ? (int8_t)idx : (int8_t)0;
        cnt += valid_intr;
        // note that __any_sync here won't work well
    }
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        int idx = tasks[i];
        shape_visitor.set_index(idx);
        float dist = variant::apply_visitor(shape_visitor, shapes[cp_base_5 + idx]);
        bool valid = dist > EPSILON && dist < min_dist;
        min_dist = valid ? dist : min_dist;
        min_index = valid ? cp_base_5 + idx : min_index;
    }
    return min_dist;

This implementation avoids convergence synchronization that happens every iteration, where there might be only parts of the threads being active. This implementation should work in the following way: for the first N iterations (N is the minimum triangle hit count), all the threads are active, and until the M+1 iteration (M is the maximum triangle hit count), the for loop exits. So... the threads are grouped, to some extent.

This implementation only takes 61ms per frame (no BVH, 531 triangles) , compared to the old code (111ms per frame).


Later @Homer512 suggests to replace int8_t tasks[32] to a bit mask. So here is latest version:
    float aabb_tmin = 0;
    unsigned int tasks = 0;          // 32 bytes

#pragma unroll
    for (int idx = 0; idx < remain_prims; idx++) {
        // if current ray intersects primitive at [idx], tasks will store it
        int valid_intr = s_aabbs[idx].aabb.intersect(ray, aabb_tmin) && (aabb_tmin < min_dist);
        tasks |= (valid_intr << idx);
        // note that __any_sync here won't work well
    }
#pragma unroll
    while (tasks) {
        int idx = __ffs(tasks) - 1; // find the first bit that is set to 1, note that __ffs is 
        tasks &= ~((unsigned int)1 << idx); // clear bit in case it is found again
        shape_visitor.set_index(idx);
        float dist = variant::apply_visitor(shape_visitor, shapes[cp_base_5 + idx]);
        bool valid = dist > EPSILON && dist < min_dist;
        min_dist = valid ? dist : min_dist;
        min_index = valid ? cp_base_5 + idx : min_index;
    }
     return min_dist;


This bit operation further boosts the rendering speed (from 60ms to 45ms each frame). I guess since I've already used too many registers (86) and spill them to L1 cache with --maxrregcount = 64 to have enough warps on the SMs, the int8_t tasks[32] might cause more unexpected register spilling, so when this part is replaced, the performance sees further improvements.

So whether have I solved the problem of BSYNC? Maybe not (as there are still some... barrier, and L2 Theoretical Sectors Global Excessive problem seems pretty severe):

, but anyway, the if convergence synchronization is no longer the most significant bottleneck and I've really learned a lot. Thanks again @Homer512 for the in-depth followup!

"int8_t tasks[32] might cause more unexpected register spilling" tasks is dynamically indexed, so it can't live in registers independent of register spilling. The compiler can only put local arrays into registers when it can resolve accesses at compile time. The accesses with cnt are data-dependent, so the array will always be stored in global memory.
